# Play! Framework - Submit button does POST to wrong link

Tags: scala, tomcat, playframework, routes, twirl

I have an api running on AWS. I use TomCat to run my Play application. I do not know much about front end and scala, but I followed a tutorial to create a Form. The problem is: the page is ok, and I can access normally. The problem is when I click in submit button... it always leads to a wrong POST url.

This is the wrong url:

```
POST /myapplication/myapplication/recoverPasswordAction
```

It should be

```
POST /myapplication/recoverPasswordAction
```

Does anybody have any idea how to solve this?

Main.scala.html:

```
@(title: String)(content: Html)

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Recuperar senha</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

      <!--  Load site-specific customizations after bootstrap. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/main.css")">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="@routes.Assets.at("images/favicon.png")">

      <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
      <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.js"></script>
          <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Recuperar senha</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

    @content
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Enable tooltips. Used primarily to validate that JQuery + Bootstrap JS are loaded. Remove this script if you don't want tooltips. -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $("[rel='tooltip']").tooltip()
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my fieldset.scala.html

```
@(changePassword: Form[views.formdata.ChangePasswordForm])

@import views.html.bootstrap3._

<fieldset>
  <!-- Header -->
  <div id="legend">
    <legend>Recuperar Senha</legend>
  </div>

   <!-- Name -->
  @password(changePassword("password"),
        label = "Senha",
        placeholder = "Nova senha",
        help = "Senha com no mínimo 4 e no máximo 12 carácteres.")

  <!-- Password -->
  @password(changePassword("confirmPassword"),
            label = "Confirmar Senha",
            placeholder = "Confirme a Nova senha",
            help = "")


  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">Confirmar</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Index.scala.html:

```
@(changePassword: Form[views.formdata.ChangePasswordForm])

@import helper._

@Main("Index") {
<div class="container">
  <div class="well">

    @form(routes.UserPasswordRecoveryController.postCreateNewPassword(), 'class -> "form-horizontal") {
      @fieldset(changePassword)
    }
  </div>

  @if(flash.containsKey("success")) {
  <div class="well">
    <div id="success-message" class="text-success">
      @flash.get("success")
    </div>
  </div>
  }
  @if(flash.containsKey("error")) {
  <div class="well">
    <div id="error-message" class="text-danger">
      @flash.get("error")
  </div>
    </div>
  }
</div>

}
```

This is my ChangePasswordForm.java

```
public class ChangePasswordForm {

    public String password;
    public String confirmPassword;
    public long userId;
    private PBKDF2Generator pbkdf2Generator;

    /** Required for form instantiation. */
    public ChangePasswordForm() {
    }



    public List<ValidationError> validate() {

        List<ValidationError> errors = new ArrayList<>();

        if (password == null || password.length() == 0) {
            errors.add(new ValidationError("password", "Por favor, digite uma senha."));
        }else if(password.length() < 4){
            errors.add(new ValidationError("password", "Por favor, digite uma senha com no mínimo 4 dígitos."));
        }else if(password.length() > 12){
            errors.add(new ValidationError("password", "Por favor, digite uma senha com no máximo 12 dígitos."));
        }else if(confirmPassword.length() == 0 || confirmPassword.equals("")){
            errors.add(new ValidationError("confirmPassword", "Por favor, digite a confirmação da senha."));
        }else if(!confirmPassword.equals(password)){
            errors.add(new ValidationError("confirmPassword", "Senha incorreta."));
        }

        if(errors.size() > 0){
            return errors;
        }else{      
            try {
                String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-", "");
                this.pbkdf2Generator = new PBKDF2Generator();
                this.password = pbkdf2Generator.generateStrongPasswordHash(password, uuid);
                this.confirmPassword = pbkdf2Generator.generateStrongPasswordHash(confirmPassword, uuid);

            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Finally the route with the action of the button that is not being called in the right way:

```
POST    /recoverPasswordAction                           controllers.UserPasswordRecoveryController.postCreateNewPassword()
```

Comment: 1. Can you include the rendered `<form>` tag so we can see the exact `action` and `method` that's being rendered? 2. Can you give the version of Play you're using. I don't know about Play 1, but Play 2 doesn't use Tomcat at all.

Comment: My Play! version is: 2.11.6. I use Play! on TomCat because it is easier to manage my environment in AWS. I generate a War file. I am going to edit my post.

Comment: I don't think 2.11.6 is Play's version since the latest version of Play is 2.6.x right now. Are you looking at the version of Scala?